# Verilog test bench state diagram

Tags: verilog

I have a homework problem that requires to make the state diagram for a mealy machine that will output a one whenever there are 3 or more 1's inputed in a row.
I came up with it, and the way that I see it is outlined in my case(state), and I have a feeling that it is correct because it compiles just fine. I think my problem here is my test bench. This is all in one file but broken up to make my explanation easier...

```
// This is my module for the state diagram
 module prob558(output reg y,input x, clk,reset);
parameter s0=2'b00,s1=2'b01,s2=2'b10,s3=2'b11;
reg [1:0] state; 
always @(posedge clk, negedge reset)
if (reset==0) state<=s0;
else
case(state)
s0: if (x==0) state<=s0 && y==0; else if(x==1)state<=s1 && y==0;
s1: if (x==0) state<=s0 && y==0; else if(x==1)state<=s2 && y==0;
s2: if (x==0) state<=s0 && y==0; else if(x==1)state<=s3 && y==0;
s3: if (x==0) state<=s0 && y==1; else if(x==1)state<=s3 && y==1;
endcase
endmodule
```

Here is where my test bench begins...What I am trying to do here is to just output the x and y to see what they come out to be

```
module prob558_tb();
reg clock;
reg reset;
reg x;
wire y;
prob558 p558(y,x,clk,reset);


// this is where I am starting to get lost, I am only trying to follow a 
// poorly explained example my professor showed us for a synchronous 
// circuit...
initial #200 $finish;
initial begin
clock = 0;
reset = 0;
#5 reset =1;
#5 clock=~clock;
end

// This I came up with my own, and although it is wrong, this is the way I am 
// thinking of it. What I am trying to do below is to have the 'x' inputs be 
// set by these numbers I am inputting, and then I was thinking it would go 
// through my case statements and  the 'y' output would be given
initial begin
#10 x=1;
#10 x=0;
#10 x=1;
#10 x=1;
#10 x=1;
#10 x=1;
#10 x=1;
#10 x=0;
#10 x=0;
end

// the following below I know is correct!
initial begin
$monitor("x= %d y=%d",x,y);
$dumpfile("prob558.vcd");
$dumpvars;
end
endmodule
```

I am getting x inputs of 0101010 and all my y outputs come out as 'y=x'
if anyone has any tips for improvement I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hint: `&&` is a logic operator; tt doesn't separate assignments. Therefore `state<=s0 && y==0;` is the same as `state <= (s0 && (y==0));` `y` is treated as an input, and is X since it never assigned. You want something like `begin state<=s0; y<=0; end` is closer to what you should use. There are far more cleaner ways to get your desired functionality and you should look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of corrections that I would like to point in your test bench and help you figure out what is wrong in your RTL code:

1. `clk` must be `clock`

   ```
   //  prob558 p558(y,x,clk,reset); <-- clk must be clock
       prob558 p558(y,x,clock,reset);
   ```
2. `clock` generation must be in an infinite loop

   ```
   //#5 clock=~clock; <-- should be inside an infinite loop

   initial begin
     forever begin
       #5 clock = ~clock;
     end
   end
   ```
3. Wait for reset before asserting some input signals

   ```
   @(posedge reset); // wait for reset
   ```
4. Synchronize your input to the `clock` by using `@(posedge clock)` instead of `#10` and use nonblocking assignment.

   ```
   // #10 x=1; <-- use @(posedge clock) instead and a non-blocking assignment
   // #10 x=0;
   // #10 x=1;
   // #10 x=1;
   // #10 x=1;
   // #10 x=1;
   // #10 x=1;
   // #10 x=0;
   // #10 x=0;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 1;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 0;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 1;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 1;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 1;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 1;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 1;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 0;
     @(posedge clock) x <= 0;
   ```

You might want to try to run the above corrections [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Nf3) and see the wave form.

Now you can try to fix the logic of your RTL code (output `y` does not output correctly, see Greg's comment) since this is your homework.